# In JavaScript, are these two pieces of code equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I am almost new to JavaScript, and I am learning about the use of the anonymous function. I have written this piece of code and test it.

Code 1:

```
function build(something) {
    return function(name) {
        alert("Here is " + something + "\nHello " + name + "!");
    };
}
```

After that I just removed the ;, but I am getting the same result.
Code 2:

```
function build(something) {
    return function(name) {
       alert("Here is " + something + "\nHello " + name + "!");
    }
}
```

The way I am calling the function is (for both cases):

```
var station = build("Station");
station();
```

Are they equivalent because in any case I am getting any error? If so, why is not needed the semicolon, and which one is mostly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolons are automatically inserted in certain situations.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

Comment: Pretty useful answer, it clearly states that JavaScript insert a semicolon automatically after a return statement :).